# Icecream Material

Tags: materials, node-editor

I am working on ice cream chocobar project and i am really struggling on the icecream texture node setup, have chocolate texture figured out but I just cant get the icecream part working, can someone help me please.

Comment: When you post questions, add pictures like ice cream texture from Google Image. Sometimes, pictures can help get your questions answered very quickly: otherwise, you'll wait longer. Thing is, majority of people have short attention span, so pictures help grab attention. Moreover, pictures help jog thoughts, spur on ideas and break Creator's Block.

Comment: Ice cream texture examples: https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=ice+cream+texture+&qs=n&form=QBIR&sp=-1&pq=ice+cream+texture+&sc=6-18&sk=&cvid=77F47756CEB14B359F83636CFF18148B

Comment: I remember something of Andrew Price's tutorial: How to make realistic bread (soda bread that Irish & Scottish eat). It may not be ice cream, but I think you will find something there, the  textured cut side of bread and the technique for making textures. Check out this video. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rrP1-ZJz3GA

Comment: I disagree with ritas 1st post, please don't post pictures just for the sake of adding images/grabbing peoples attention. I would rather read a well formatted wall of text than a having to scroll multiple times to reach the end of the post. However, this question can be improved by showing your current state of your work and your previous progress. Post a picture of your 'ice cream' node setup and it render preview result. Then add a clear explanation what you wish to improve. Actually **describe** your problems with the current setup/result in more detail than "*just cant get [it] working*".

Comment: You should also add your renderer, are you creating a node setup in Cycles, Internal or Eevee?